# Метод POST не видит виртуальных обьектов (добавленых через append())

Tags: jquery, php

jQuery код добавляет новый виртуальный обьект ".add" к ".main"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.main').on('click', '.add', function (){
    $('.main').append('<div class="add">Next element</div><input type="hidden" name="param[]"
value="Next element"/>'); 
     }); 
}); 
</script>
```

HTML код с "main" формой:

```
<form action="" method="post"
class="main">
<div class="add">First element</div>
<input type="hidden" name="param[]" value="First element"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="go"/> </form>
```

PHP итерует полученый массив "param"

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    foreach ($_POST['param'] as $element) 
    {
       echo '<br/>'.$element;
    } 
}
```

проблема в том что в массиве не будет елементов добавленых через jQuery

Comment: ваш код рабочий, ошибка в другом месте.

Comment: Поддерживаю @Yura Ivanov. Сделайте простую проверку и посмотрите результат:

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        print_r($_POST['param']);
        exit();
    }

P.S. И вот еще что - не уверен, что вам необходимо делегировано обрабатывать событие click на элементах. Поэтому попробуйте убрать селектор **'.add'** и добавлять элементы так:

    $('.main').on('click', function (){
        $('.main').append('<div class="add">Next element</div><input type="hidden" name="param[]" value="Next element"/>'); 
    });